# PHP DOMDocument is not rendering Unicode Characters Properly

Tags: php, unicode, domdocument

I am using CKEditor for letting the user to post comments, user can also put the unicode characters in the comment box.

When I submit the Form and Check the $_POST["reply"], the unicode characters are shown very well. I have also used `header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the top of the page 
But When I process it using PHP DOMDocument, all the characters become unreadable.

```
$html_unicode = "xyz unicode data";
$html_data = '<body>'.$html_unicode . '</body>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_data );

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
```

When I echo

```
echo $dom->textContent;
```

The Output becomes

```
§Ø³ÙØ¨ÙÙ ÙÙÚº ØºØ±ÙØ¨ Ú©Ù Ø¢ÙÛ ÙÛÙ
```

How Can I get the proper unicode characters back using PHP DOMDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank God I got the Solution By Just Replacing

```
$html_data = '<body>'.$html_unicode . '</body>';
```

with

```
$html_data = '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head><body>' . $html_unicode . '</body>';
```

Comment: This one worked for me.

I just did this:
    $content = str_replace('</head>', '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>', $content);

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me:

```
$html_unicode = "xyz unicode data";
$html_data = '<body>'.$html_unicode . '</body>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html_data  = mb_convert_encoding($html_data , 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'); // require mb_string
$dom->loadHTML($html_data);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
```

Comment: Or, shorter, just `$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html_data);`

Answer (score 7):

Try this :)

```
<?php
    $html_unicode = "xyz unicode data";
    $html_data = '<body>'.$html_unicode . '</body>';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html_data );

    $elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
    echo utf8_decode($dom->textContent);
?>
```

Comment: That only works for characters in ISO-8859-1. The OP is using Arabic.

Comment: *Converts a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1*. ISO-8859-1 does not have Arabic characters.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for arabic langauge

```
<?php
echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1256\"></head><body>";
$html = file_get_contents("    url    ");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$ExTEXT = $dom->getElementById('tag id');
echo utf8_decode($ExTEXT->textContent);
echo "</body></html>";
```